# ftp file upload fails when special character is present in password

Tags: c, macos, ftp

I was trying to upload a file through application i wrote in c.
As i did not find any **API**, i decided to go through commands.
Input command line looked like this.

```
ftp -u ftp://ftpuser:password@123@x.x.x.x/test.txt /tmp/test.txt
```

Whenever a special character is present, login will fail. when i tried with different user without any special characters in the password upload works.

How this issue can be resolved or is there any another method available like **API** which can be made use of.

If any sample code available then it will be of great help.

Special character means `@`, `$`, `#` (Ex : `password@123`, `password$123`)

code snippet:

```c
RunCommandWithPipe(PSTRING CmdLine)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int status;


    fp = popen(CmdLine, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
            ErrGen(constErrOpenFile);
    }

    status = pclose(fp);
    if (status == -1)
    {
            ErrGen(constErrCloseFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code. How are you calling the command? system? popen? What are the special characters? How are they special? Are they special to the shell? Are they Unicode characters that happen to contain a NULL byte? Also, is that example ftp command correct? Why are there two @ symbols in there? Is the password supposed to be "password@123"?

Comment: yes password is "password@123". yes above example is of format ftp -u ftp://username:password@host/path "source location". i tried manually through terminal and it worked when there was no special characters present in password

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this doesn't work is because you are passing unfiltered meta characters into the shell. This is very dangerous. If someone untrustworthy gets to decide the value of any of the parameters to your ftp command, such as the username, password, ftp server, or file name, then that person will be able to run arbitrary shell commands.

You can see what's going on by putting an "echo" in front of your ftp command:

```
echo ftp -u ftp://ftpuser:password$123@x.x.x.x/test.txt /tmp/test.txt
```

You'll get this result:

```
ftp -u ftp://ftpuser:password23@x.x.x.x/test.txt /tmp/test.txt
```

The shell is trying to evaluate $1 as a variable, leaving an empty result.

There's a couple of things you can do.

1) Make the command safe by escaping all the meta characters. Here you need to be very careful, using a whitelist approach rather than just trying to get rid of the special characters you've thought of. In the whitelist approach you accept that some set of characters are safe, such as [A-Za-z0-9:_-]. Every other character you either strip out or escape by preceding it with a backslash. (eg. "foo:bar$baz&abc" becomes "foo:bar\$bazabc") If you do this way don't try to think of all the characters you know of that are special and escape those. You will most likely forget some, and not handle input this like:

```
ftp -u ftp://ftpuser:; rm -rf /;echo @x.x.x.x/test.txt /tmp/test.txt
```

2) Don't pass arguments on the shell, instead control the FTP client through fread()/fwrite() on the pipe that popen() gave you.

In this case what you do is launch the ftp client with no arguments. Then you write "OPEN 192.168.1.1" or wherever you want to connect. Then you write the username. Then you write the password. Then you write the GET or PUT command want. Then you write "EXIT" or write an EOF. You should read the result codes from the server. You'll get 200 series results on success. You'll get a 500 series result if the login is bad, etc.

You still have to watch out when piping into the FTP command because it will take shell escapes like "!rm -rf /", but there is much less opportunity for that than on the shell. You just need to make sure the strings you get to build your FTP commands are one line and that you always precede them with a valid FTP command. You should also watch out for any funny business with untrustworthy filenames. (eg. don't allow absolute paths, "..", and so forth)

Comment: Hi i tried your suggestion but i encountered problem in between 1. "cd" command did not work for logging into remote machine directory , always gave 500 error saying wrong command after so many search i found "CWD" it worked like charm, then to change directory on local machine i used "lcd" and this is not working now and i am unable to move to next(PUT) command because of this issue. Please let me know if any solution available for this.

Comment: In my answer I accidentally capitalized the FTP commands. The commands send on the control channel are all caps, however the commands to the ftp(1) client that you're writing are not. My bad. You can do stuff like this: get remotename.txt /tmp/localname.txt

Answer (score 0):

You propably using a wrong charset to send the password

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer